# Maintenance plan and job in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Attached image copy of SQL Server 2008 R2 database table. In that table daily updated huge amount of data for Syslog, Security log, Application, System log
so our database is growing very rapidly.

Is there any maintenance plan or job so I can purge data automatically which older than 180 days.

[image]

Comment: @marc_s is there any idea create job??

Comment: jobs can be created manually with any t-sql code you'd like

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from tableX where DATEADD(month, -6, GETDATE()) > timestampfield
```

This will purge all fields older than 6 months.